# How to open my electron program when a link (like myprogram://a/a) is clicked in a web browser

Tags: html, google-chrome, electron

I want to transfer information from my website to my electron program by using a link that has some data in it (like myprogram://data). But can't seem to find any info on the internet about this. Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I think that is a job for a backend service. I am not an expert in backend myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register your app as a protocol handler using [`app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appsetasdefaultprotocolclientprotocol-path-args)

```js
app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient("myprogram")
```

On Windows, when the "myprogram://data" link is clicked, a new instance of your application will be launched and the arguments will be included in [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv)

Use [`app.requestSingleInstanceLock`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#apprequestsingleinstancelock) if you don't want multiple instances of your app to be running

On macOS, you can get the arguments using the [`open-url`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-open-url-macos) event